# Extract match data from this web "http://bet.hkjc.com/football/index.aspx?lang=en"

Tags: vba, web-scraping, automation

I want to extract match data from this web site "http://bet.hkjc.com/football/index.aspx?lang=en" using the following code :

```
Sub Macro4()
' Macro4 Macro
' steve lau 在 28/04/2016 錄製的巨集
baseURL = "http://www.hkjc.com/chinese/news/redirect_odds_ch_football.asp"
baseName = "summary"
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & baseURL _
    , Destination:=Range("A1"))
End With
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = baseName
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
End With    

End Sub
```

But nothing was returned. I think it may due to different frames in the web page. Could anyone can help to figure out how to extract the match details ?
Many thanks.

Comment: The code you are proposing is not suitable to extract data from that website. You'll have to write your own web scraping tool. There are many questions and answers in this respect here on SO. [Just do a search...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D+%5Bvba%5D+scraping)

Comment: Thx you for your advice. The web scraping is a new idea to me (know too little abt vba). I will try and see if the problem can be solved. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script where I grab the table using a

```
 .document.getElementById("footballmaincontent").getElementsByTagName("table")(2)
```

and then loop the rows and columns (cells within row) within the table.

---

**Sample results on page on 14/06/2018**

[image: Sample results]

Matches output from script:

[image: Output from script]

---

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, a As HTMLTable
    Const URL = "http://bet.hkjc.com/football/index.aspx?lang=en"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set a = .document.getElementById("footballmaincontent").getElementsByTagName("table")(2)

        Dim r As Long, c As Long, iRow As HTMLTableRow, iCell As HTMLTableCell

        With ActiveSheet
            For Each iRow In a.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                For Each iCell In iRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    Select Case iCell.innerText
                    Case "Home", "Draw", "Away"
                    Case Else
                        c = c + 1: .Cells(r + 1, c) = iCell.innerText
                    End Select
                Next iCell
                c = 0: r = r + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**References required (VBE > Tools > References)**

1. HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls